# Drupal 7 Content Deadline

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am using Drupal 7 and a custom CCK content in order to allow users to submit information to our website.  I'd like to be able to only allow submissions between a set of user definable dates.  Once the dates expire, i'd like for the user to receive a message of some sort stating that the deadline for submissions is now expired when they click the link to open the form.

I currently manually go in and turn off permissions to the content type once the deadline expires, but that is clunky and requires a little too much management (I have 15 forms I need to do this for).  I've searched stack overflow and google and have not come up with anything that fit my needs, most likely because I'm not using the right keywords.

Does anyone know an easy way to do this with a module or do I need to try to write my own in order to accomplish this goal?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you have to write some custom  module to achieve this. You would use hook_node_access() to control node creation page access and and put your error message and/or redirection.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7

2. Another solution is to use Webform module.
   https://www.drupal.org/project/webform

   - Download version 7.x-4.x
   - Create a form and in the settings there is an option to control total submissions limit, and set time frames for limitations.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by:

1. Create a column in user table in mysql called "expDate", assign the expDate values(mm-dd-yyyy) to each user
2. In drupal, on the page where users summit message, write php code to grab the expDate from database, and compare it to Current Date, date('mm-dd-yyyy'). Just copy can paste the php codes in each page where you have the form.
3. You can also pass the expDate from php to js, then do some fancy job instead of simple alert.